# Symfony Native Debian

Tags: php, symfony, debian

I installed symfony 2.8 on debian 9. Using native packages from the link repository.
[Debian9 Package Symfony](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php-symfony)

Installed several components that use symfony, for example doctrine, twig, asset, etc.
In debian they were divided between /var/lib/dpkg and /usr/share folders.
In /var/lib/dpkg it is displayed that in the info folder are the .list of each component.
[Result folder info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRSoR.png)

I searched for related information to make a "hello world" by displaying the native symfony and it's really little or nothing I got.
I have used and implemented projects in symfony in a traditional way with versions 2.8, 3.x. And I really can't emulate it with the native, as you would normally work.

Has anyone managed to deploy symfony natively?

Any help or tip will be welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "natively"? Is there any reason to use such an outdated version and not use the common way to install Symfony using composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for the answer.

Well, it's really a test, I was asking about the native packages in debian and I had already successfully tested wordpress (of course, the same in a version before the last one). 
All this motivated that in the place where I currently work I perform functions of infrastructure and programmer, and therefore a group of colleagues and myself have tried to unify the security updates with the operating system and minimize what needs to be updated.

Comment: Try something similar to what worked for us in Wordpress https://wiki.debian.org/WordPress, however until now the attempts have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Package from debian seems to install symfony 2.8 and the docs for this are:
https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/creating-the-project.html

Simply by using:

```
symfony new blog
```

this should generate a basic app for you and then you should run

```
php app/console server:run
```

and if you visit `http://localhost:8000/` in your browser you should see your app according to 
https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup.html